# deserialize html form in server with websocket

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, forms, websocket

I'm sending the contents of a form to the server via `WebSocket`, like this:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/dh");
var formdata = $('eventForm').serialize();
ws.onopen = function()
{
    ws.send(formdata);
};
```

It is received on the server here:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    print 'message received %s' % message
```

How do I deserialize the form data on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be a query string, so one way would be to use [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
import urlparse
⋮
data = urlparse.parse_qs(message)
```

`data` will be a dict representing the form.

In Python 3, it’s `urllib.parse` instead of `urlparse`.